# Could not format name node in cantos java.lang.Internal Error

Tags: hadoop

I have attached image which shows the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this by running:

```
$ sudo yum update
```

and then attempting to format the namenode again.

It seems my installation of CentOS had some out-of-date packages, and the format (and startup of the namenode) worked after the update.